Question Limitations
What are the rules and question Limitations in Reverse Engineering?
Some Questions seems to ask for help in cracking. Is that legitimate? Are we allowed to answer him even if he specifies the program which is working on?
Hope you got the point

See https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/asking

I read the page. but didn't find the answer I am looking for. maybe you can put a direct link to the point please

The first two links on that page explain the "Question Limitations".

Unfortunately this is a rather "fluid" link. It's contents can change. Just as on the main site you should provide more context than merely a link, even though the answer was accepted at the time. At the time of this writing there is no mentioning of "cracking" or "hacking", for example. Neither is there a mention of legal/illegal in these first two links, except in the footer (Legal).
